# How to delete S3 files in a object every 10 min after creation without CLI or script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I been asked in interview **How to delete S3 files in a object every 10 min after creation without CLI or script?**

Any service or option present in AWS to does such job ?

Comment: If you are applying for a job that requires AWS skills, I would highly recommend reading the [Amazon S3 Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Welcome.html). It contains a wealth of useful information and you'll actually learn a lot. It's big, so rather than reading every word you should at least read all the headings, look at the pictures and read parts of it that take your interest. If an employer is going to pay for your knowledge, then you should invest time into gaining that knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS S3 lifecycle configuration to delete the objects without the use of CLI or script

More details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html)

Following is the extract from that page

> To manage your objects so that they are stored cost effectively
>   throughout their lifecycle, configure their lifecycle. A lifecycle
>   configuration is a set of rules that define actions that Amazon S3
>   applies to a group of objects. There are two types of actions:
>
> **Transition actions**—Define when objects transition to another storage class. For example, you might choose to transition
>   objects to the STANDARD_IA storage class 30 days after you created
>   them, or archive objects to the GLACIER storage class one year after
>   creating them.
>
> **Expiration actions**—Define when objects expire. Amazon S3 deletes expired objects on your behalf

Comment: In life cycle you expire an object/file with minimum of 1 day ! you cannot expire object on hours or minutes basis.